# Check if HTTP Methods have been Allowed and Enabled on Localhost

Tags: lamp, rhel6, telnet, netcat

I’m running Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) on a RHEL system.  My LAMP is running on localhost.

I want to check if the HTTP methods:

- POST
- GET
- PUT
- DELETE

are allowed and enabled.

I’ve read that they can be checked with netcat or telnet https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Test_HTTP_Methods_(OTG-CONFIG-006)

When I try netcat, this is what I get:

```
[root@joseph ~]# nc localhost 80
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 15 Sep 2017 20:17:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Content-Length: 302
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not     understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

When I try telnet, this is what I get:

```
[root@joseph ~]# telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0
Host localhost

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 15 Sep 2017 19:48:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Content-Length: 302
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not     understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I understand that getting a "400 Bad Request" can be due to malformed syntax https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

But when I’m just sending telnet or netcat commands, how could that be?

Comment: why you don't use curl?

Comment: Down voters:  please give reasons

Comment: Thank you @c4f4t0r for that excellent advice.  That was my answer!  I ran `curl -i -X OPTIONS localhost`.  That worked; there was no "Bad Request".  On the fourth line, from curl, I saw what I was hoping to see:  `Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither your `nc` attempt nor your `telnet` attempt provided a valid HTTP `Host` request header. It is not allowed to send an HTTP/1.1 request without this header, and such requests must be rejected with a 400 Bad Request response.

In the first case it was missing, and in the second case it was indeed malformed.

That header should have appeared as:

```
Host: localhost
```